# bq Ubuntu phone with congstar prepaid surf stick

Tags: phone

I am using the bq Ubuntu Phone - which by-the-way is absoulte awesome - with the SIM card of my Congstar SurfStick (prepaid). The SurfStick comes with a small PC-software to connect and it has a fix 24hour rate.
My HUAWEI mobil WiFi auto-connects when switching on.

Can I switch on/off the data connection with the Ubuntu aswell?

Thanks and regards,
Jann

Answer (score 0):

In Settings / Network you can enable/disable mobile data. You can also switch on/off data roaming and the speed 2G/3G there.